# How can I display value of pivot table ? Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, pivot, laravel-5.3, has-and-belongs-to-many, belongs-to

I have 3 model : store model, product model, order model

store model is like this :

```
class Store extends Model
{   
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'user', 'address', 'phones', 'email', 'photo'];
    ...
}
```

product model is like this :

```
class Product extends Model
{
    protected  $fillable = ['store_id','category_id','name', 'photo','description'];
    ...
}
```

order model is liket this :

```
class Order extends Model
{
    ...
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'orders_products')
            ->withPivot('sub_total','quantity','price','information')->withTimestamps();
    }
    public function store()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Store::class);
    }
}
```

I have 4 table : stores table, orders table, products table, orders_products table

orders_producs table is pivot table

In view blade laravel I call this :

```
<a href="javascript:">{{ $order->store->name }}</a>
```

It works. It success display store name

My problem is when I want to display product name

In view blade laravel I try :

```
<a href="javascript:">{{ $order->products->name }}</a>
```

There exist error :

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$id
>   (View:...

It seems the wrong way of calling

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's `belongsToMany()`, you can display data like this:

```
@foreach ($order->products as $product)
    {{ $product->name }}
    {{ $product->pivot->price }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks  bro. You are so great